# chef-configure site in IIS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, chef-recipe, appcmd

while executing the below cookbook to configure a site in IIS,

```
chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[cookbooksample::web]'
```

I am getting the error

> "cannot create a file when that file already exists"  Ran
>   C:\windows\system32\appcmd.exe start sitename:"testapp" and return
>   183.

I verified no such file exists and even tried by changing different application pool and website name.

where it went wrong?

Comment: Please comment before vote down so that i can correct if required.

Comment: I guess. May be you could elaborate little more about your error / usage / configuration by editing the question?

Comment: Thank you..I updated the question.

Comment: Honestly: you went wrong when you tried to deploy a Rails App on Windows. It's a lonely, bumpy road. Get a Linux box. (This is not a Windows rant. Rails and Windows just don't go together well)